# A Hecke-Maass eigenbasis for the space of Maass cusp newforms

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms, hecke-algebras

I heard that the space of Maass cusp newforms on $\Gamma_0(N)/\mathbb{H}$ has a basis of Hecke eigenforms.

Would anyone happen to know of a reference of this fact? Or, even better, how to prove it?

Comment: Aren't the Maass forms also including the modular forms? (up to a $y^{k/2}$ term) Most newforms aren't eigenforms, but the vector space $S_k(\Gamma_0(N))^{new}$ has a basis of newforms.

Comment: I could extend my question to modular forms. Did you mean to say that $M_k(\Gamma_0(N))^{\text{new}}$ has a basis of Hecke-eigenforms however? If so, then I seek proof.

Comment: Ah yes, my question was a bit ill-phrased, I will rephrase it.

Comment: For the Maass forms you'll have some troubles due to infinite dimensionality of $S_k(\Gamma_0(N))_{Maass}$ (weight lowering). That's where assuming the automorphic representation is irreducible helps. Or maybe there is a definition of the new subspace making it finite dimensional? For holomorphic modular forms it suffices to simultaneously diagonalize the Hecke operators.

Comment: Ok, let's consider the babycase of modular forms. I am still confused with regards to at which point does one use the fact that our forms are newforms?

Comment: The Hecke operators need to commute to simultaneously diagonalize, if you look only at $T_n,\gcd(n,N)=1$ then you don't need the new subspace, which is there only to include the remaining Hecke operators in our commutative algebra (as well as the Fricke involution), an algebra of matrices since $S_k(\Gamma_0(N))$ is finite dimensional, and they are normal for the Petersson inner product.